# How to add types from external assembly to toolbox control? (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, assemblies, toolbox

I am trying to do something like this in my WPF application:

```
    ToolboxControl ctrl = new ToolboxControl();
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
    var category = new ToolboxCategory(assembly.GetName().Name);
    foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        var wrapper = new ToolboxItemWrapper(t, t.Name);
        category.Add(wrapper);
    }
    ctrl.Categories.Add(category);
```

i.e. adding ToolboxItemWrappers for each type found in an assembly. However the last line throws the following exception (see image)

[http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/2261/7xvqv.png http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/2261/7xvqv.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/2261/7xvqv.png)

All dependencies of the external assembly are also referenced in the main (WPF) application. So what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the CustomLibrary assembly in the file? If not, hook to this event AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve in you app, and load any other assemblies that the assembly at the filePath references to. It is required if CustomLibrary or other dlls are not in GAC.

Comment: I suggest you hook to the AssemblyResolve event and put a breakpoint. You would know what all Types are being referred to and which of the dependencies CLR is not able to find.

Comment: You're right. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600688/how-to-make-an-external-assembly-available-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Assembly.LoadFile` to load the assembly through reflection. However this method does not automatically find dependencies in the same directory. You should use `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

Also take in consideration that `LoadFrom` goes through Fusion allowing the load request to be redirected to another assembly while `LoadFile` loads exactly what you requested.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! What is fusion?

Comment: I tried changing `LoadFile` to `LoadFrom` and it still does not work.

Comment: Fusion is the assembly loader component of the CLR. Assuming the exception you get when CustomLibrary is requested goes through Fusion you can use [Fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to verify why the assembly fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "CustomLisbrary" is installed in GAC. Additionally, You may want to create design.dll and VisualStudio.design.dll.