# How to make an external assembly available at runtime?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594968/how-to-add-types-from-external-assembly-to-toolbox-control-wpf) and apparently the problem is where I can load an assembly using Reflection's `Assembly.LoadFile` or `Assembly.LoadFrom`, and get the type inside that assembly, the assembly is still not accessible in the whole application. So when WPF tries to resolve a type, it doesn't find that type because it doesn't find the assembly.

My question is, can I reference an assembly at runtime, so that it will be resolvable by WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add types from external assembly to toolbox control? (WPF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594968/how-to-add-types-from-external-assembly-to-toolbox-control-wpf)

Comment: You haven't provided any new info in this duplicate question.

Comment: I'm not posting a duplicate question. I am making the question more general so it would also apply in different situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works for me is handling the [`CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += 
    new ResolveEventHandler(OnAssemblyResolveFailure);

Assembly OnAssemblyResolveFailure(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        Assembly assembly = .. //some logic here to load the assembly from assembly name
        return assembly;
    }
```

This way if the application cannot resolve an assembly name it will call your handler to find it